# Why does cPython on Windows not have curses?

Tags: python, windows, cpython

On Linux, when you have cPython installed you can simply `import curses`, but that is not the case on Windows.

I only found [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html):

> The Windows version of Python doesn’t include the curses module.

What is the reason for this inconsistency?

Comment: I know this is not your question, but some might be interested to see how can they use `curses` in windows, so I put it here. You could download it from here, https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses. There's also a github project which hasn't been updated in a while. https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/windows-curses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python module is only wrapper around system library for unix-like systems - `curses`. There is a port for Windows - [PDCurses](https://pdcurses.org), but user need to install it separately and it is not solid as original library.

You can try to use one of libraries like [zephyrproject-rtos
/
windows-curses](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/windows-curses)